# Javascript syntax for including html text input element into if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to add an if statement to my Javascript, so that if a text input element hasn't been filled out yet, then to do something (in this case set total to 0), otherwise carry on.

`if ($('#pledge') === "")` is the line I can't get quite right.

Here is my attempt...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var $total = $('#total'),
    $value = $('.value');
    $firstName = $('#firstname');
    $lastName = $('#lastname');
    $tour = $('#tour');
    $pledge = $('#pledge');
    $currency = $('#currency');
    $distance = $('#distance');
    $riders = $('#riders');
        $(':input').on('input change', function(e) {
    var total = 1;
    $value.each(function(index, elem) {
        if (!isNaN( parseFloat(this.value) ))
        total = total * parseFloat(this.value);
    });

if ($('#pledge') === "")
 {
 $total.val(0);
 }
else
 {
 $total.val(total / 10);
 }

    $('#pledgefirstname').text($firstName.val());
    $('#pledgelastname').text($lastName.val());
    $('#pledgetour').text($tour.val());
    $('#pledgepledge').text($pledge.val());
    $('#pledgecurrency').text($currency.val());
    $('#pledgecurrency2').text($currency.val());
    $('#pledgecurrency3').text($currency.val());
    $('#pledgecurrency4').text($currency.val());
    $('#pledgetotal').text($total.val());
    $('#pledgetotal2').text($total.val());
    $('#pledgedistance').text($distance.val());
    $('#pledgeriders').text($riders.val());
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you want $('#pledge').val()

Comment: You can use `val()` in other parts of your code, but in that particular `if`?

Comment: And "===" means "super-exactly equal to".  Probably "==" is fine (with just two equal signs).

Comment: @BrettFromLA `===` means "type equals" (both value and data type).  It's useful if you are doing a lot of computation because it doesn't try to convert it first, saving cycles.  I always use `===` whenever I can.

Comment: @JosephMarikle Thanks. I hadn't thought of saving cycles; I was just thinking that matching the TYPE of an object's property (which was empty) might be a little too strict. But your explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `#pledge` is an input your code should be

```
if ($('#pledge').val() === "")
```